# laravel react axios deploy to heroku problem

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, heroku-postgres

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duCjw.png)

Problem with laravel react axios rest api deployment in heroku postgres.
Login is okay in local but when i deploy into heroku and try it again i encounter this error.